# Loading recent messages at the bottom and putting a Load old message button to load older messages on TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I need to show the messages in chronological(latest at bottom) order, but need to display last 20 and there should be 'load old' button on top fetch older.

But for fetching from core data we could specify the sort descriptor based on which it fetched either older or recent, the problem is that it sorts in the specified order.

I.e. If I fetching recent messages it puts that message on top rather on the bottom.

Is there a way to search from recent to older, but show from older to recent(chronological order)?

code: 
`NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];` gives in the chronological order, but searches from older to recent.

`NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];` gives in the reverse chronological order, but searches from recent to older.

I need chronological ordering in which search happens from recent to older based on time stamp.

More Code:

```
-(void) loadMoreContent{ // to load older messages
    numberOfCells += 10; //number of rows
    int tempNumofCells=(signed)[self.group.messages count]; // total number of messages
    if (tempNumofCells-numberOfCells >=0) { // number of cells that we are showing is lesser
        ;
    }
    else numberOfCells = tempNumofCells;

    //--making a performFetch Request to fill up above cells--
    NSError* error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        exit(-1); // Fail
    }
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        //change the fetchRequest (fix for a bug result of constant fetched objects from fetchedController)
       if (((signed)[self.group.messages count] - numberOfCells) > 0) {
            [_fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setFetchOffset:[self.group.messages count] - numberOfCells];
        }
        else  [_fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setFetchOffset:0];

        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    .
    .
    .
  }
```

...

'setFetchOffset' has worked because I am telling to fetchedController to fetch the messages from the specified index (which is set in loadMoreContent()), again the numberOfRows of table is decided by numberOfCells variable and fetchedResults of fetchedController.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get the data from the database and then store it in an array in your model, then you could sort that array on the date order you want and store that in your model ready for your tableview.

Or in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of returning the object at position `indexRow`, return the object in your array that is at position `(arrayLength - indexRow)` which will return it in the opposite direction.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to post some code that shows what you are doing then, so we don't have to guess?

Comment: I am not getting the elements into any array, for accessing a message fetchcontroller's objectAtIndexPath function. How could I get the sorting I needed?

Comment: sorry for delay, as the fetchedResultsController returns the sorted list either chronological or reverse chronological order I need chronological ordered message list with most recent at the bottom.

Comment: I guess post is explanatory. Thanks.

Comment: Where's your code for populating the TableView (eg cellForRowAtIndexPath)?